# ClickHouse connection refused after shut down Linux OS (error Code: 210. DB::NetException: Connection refused)

Tags: linux, database, olap, clickhouse

I saw a previous post on StackOverflow related to my question. I tried to handle this connection problem by entering `sudo nano /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml`
Then, put `<listen_host>::</listen_host>` enabled in that config file, but the problem still exists.
Yesterday I connected to ClickHouse server normally. But after shut down Linux OS (runs on VMWare), today I turn on again and got this connection refused problem. All solutions I searched on the internet couldn't solve this issue. Please tell me how to solve it.
Below is the screenshot of the commands I used:

[image]

Comment: Look at the log-files: *var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log*. It can be that ClickHouse is starting for long time, try to wait for several minutes before connecting.

Comment: did you try to add ```<listen_host>0.0.0.0</listen_host>``` ?

Comment: Yes. I also tried with <listen_host>127.0.0.1</listen_host>, <listen_host>::1</listen_host>... All of the solutions I found on the internet did not work. So I only have 1 way that removed Linux OS image in VMWare and re-install. What a time-consuming way!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem after I did:

```
sudo service clickhouse-server restart
```

and cancelled action during restart.
This simple command solved the issue:

```
sudo clickhouse start
```